# How to debug the error "String resource ID #0x0"

Tags: java, android

I want to get the value of the selected item when I select the item in the list view.

```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String data = getText(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

In this code, `String data = getText(position).toString()`, I get this error:

> a String resource ID #0x0

This code is add listview

```
void DBadd() {
    String name = addTxt1.getText().toString();
    String info = addTxt2.getText().toString();
    if (name.equals("") || info.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "정보를 입력해 주세요", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (null, '" + name + "', '" + info + "');");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "추가 성공", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        addTxt1.setText(""); //입력시 EditText에 입력된값 지움
        addTxt2.setText("");
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tableName", null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);    //엑티비티의 생명주기와 커서의 생명주기를 같게 한다.

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            adapter.add(cursor.getString(1));
            adapter2.add(cursor.getString(2));
        }


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    }
}
```

How do I get the value of a selected item?

Comment: What's `getText()`? what are you trying to do?

Comment: What you just do is trying to invoke https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getText(int) method passing clicked item positions as resource id? Waaat? Of course there is no such resource

Comment: I tried to get the price from position.
Ultimately, all I want is to put the selected item in the list view on the toast.

Comment: Where is the `price` in your code? The ListView only returns the index of where the list it. it does not return the index of your items.

Comment: How should I display the selected items in the listview? I've been wandering for days......

Comment: In the DBadd function, enter in the list view to output the list view.
I'd like to click on one of the printed list views to get the item from the list view I clicked on.

Comment: I am using a translator because I am not good at English.
I'm sorry.

Comment: `int position` is the index of row in ListView you are clicked on. Knowing the set of items and position of selected item get item by position from your set and display it)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I knew position is index.
Do I have to use id? My head is bursting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String data = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**Or**, just fetch the string value directly from `adapter` using `.get(postion)` like that :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String data = adapter.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much.
It was very helpful. So I could take a step forward. I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure did i understood your question correctly, but let me guess the desired behavior:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textViewOfTheClickedRaw = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            String data = textViewOfTheClickedRaw.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

This is how you can get the value of TextView from `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

---

But I really doesn't think this is how things should work in your app

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply.
It's 1:35 a.m. Korean time. I'll try. Thank you very much.